# Understanding namespaces and their use better

Tags: c#, namespaces

One article about namespaces says

> Namespaces are C# program elements designed to help you organize your
>   programs. They also provide assistance in avoiding name clashes
>   between two sets of code. Implementing Namespaces in your own code is
>   a good habit because it is likely to save you from problems later when
>   you want to reuse some of your code. For example, if you created a
>   class named Console, you would need to put it in your own namespace to
>   ensure that there wasn't any confusion about when the System.Console
>   class should be used or when your class should be used.

Now imagine as in above statement I indeed created a `Console` class inside my namespace called: `myNamespace`.

Now at some point when someone wants to use say my library, he/she will have to do:

```
using myNamespace;
```

but likely she will need to do

```
using System;
```

too.

So we still have a clash. If I type `Console`, which console am I referring to?
How is this problem solved using namespaces?

PS. extra: also how namespaces work under the hood: I remember somewhere I read compiler just prepends functions for example with namespace to find their definitions?

Is this that? Is namespace really nothing just a  means to group code?

Comment: It will not compile until the namespaces and usings are correct. If you use properties which are not ambiguous in your namespaces you are fine.

Comment: @SebastianSchulz Don't understand what you are trying to say

Comment: You cannot compile your C# project until all errors are corrected. The compiler will show an error if there are ambigous classes/properties are used. You can use the full qualified name of the class to correct an error like this: `myNameSpace.Console.....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would not include both using statements. 
You choose, so your code looks cleaner:

```
using System;

public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("I'm here!");
    myNameSpace.Console.PopBeer("Mo beer!"); 
}
```

for practical purposes, if you have a really long namespace, you can use aliases too:

```
using System;
using sexyNs = myProject.AwesomeSolution.Helpers;

public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("I'm here!");
    sexyNs.Console.PopBeer("Mo beer!"); 
}
```

Comment: aha,this makes sense. also if you can answer extra part of my question would be nice.

Comment: Yes, the compiler will typically generate a super-short unique namespace for each symbol under compilation in order to keep the references aphart. In your code, the compiler will not understand 2 namespaces from using that uses the same name (in this example Console) but if you choose, like I did, or use aliases, like other answer this, it will compile, and prepend somehting in front of the generated objects. :)

Answer (score 5):

If you use both of the namespaces, you will either have to fully qualify the usages(`System.Console()`), or use namespace/type aliases(`Console2`) to disambiguate the types.

```
using Console1 = myNamespace;
using Console2 = System;

public void MyMethod()
{
 Console1.Console(); // or myNamespace.Console()
 Console2.Console(); // or System.Console()
}
```

Comment: can you please provide example without aliases? I am not familiar with it

Comment: See the comments. if you don't want to use aliases. Wherever you want to use console. You have to give the full namespace. e.g. `System.Console(); or myNamespace.Console();` in all the places wherever you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The program will not compile. You need to instantiate your classes like this:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("hi");
myNamespace.Console y = .... ;
```

Answer (score 0):

a better solution would be to avoid using names which cause conflicts. Name your Console something else so it's clear which one you use when you need to.

Answer (score 0):

@user200300,already many have given exact code solution to your problem description.But let me try to explain clearly.Namespaces also provide assistance in avoiding names clashes.

For example:Lets say there is a single project called Stackoverflow and it contains two teams say TeamA and TeamB.

```
namespace Stackoverflow 
{
namespace TeamA
 {
   class classA
    {
       public static void Print()
       {
      Console.WriteLine("Print A");
       }
    }
 }
}


namespace Stackoverflow 
{
namespace TeamB
 {
   class classA
    {
       public static void Print()
       {
      Console.WriteLine("Print B");
       }
    }
 }
}
```

Here both the team TeamA and TeamB are trying to modify same class classA.Namespaces have helped in organizing the code in efficient and in proper accessible way.
If you want to access the print method from any team you outside these namespaces or from any class for that matter you would write like

```
Stackoverflow.TeamA.classA.Print();
Stackoverflow.TeamB.classA.Print();
```

So above code is cumbersome and lengthy and its not clean.Hence aliases can be used .

```
using STAP=Stackoverflow.TeamA;
using STBP=Stackoverflow.TeamB();
```

Now you can access easily.

```
STAP.classA.print();//TeamA's print method.
```

Thus a namespace can contain **Namespace,Class,Inteface,struct,enum,delegate**